# ASIHTTPRequest build-in authentication dialog is removing my MBProgressHUD. How can I show it again?

Tags: objective-c, ios, asihttprequest, mbprogresshud

I am trying to show my download progress with MBProgressHUD. I am using the following code:

```
[HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(downloadFile) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];
```

The server is on basic http authentication. If I provide the username and password, then it works fine; showing the progress indicator. But If the password is wron or not provided from code then the authentication dialogue comes and asks the user for credential(in this process, removes my hud). After that, it continues the download without showing the HUD. How can I display my HUD after the authentication prompt is dismissed?

Comment: and yes, I am performing and asynchronous request.

Answer (score 0):

First of, if you're doing an asynchronous request than avoid using the `showWhileExecuting: onTarget:withObject:animated:` method. Take a look at the NSURLRequest sample ([this](https://github.com/matej/MBProgressHUD/blob/master/Demo/Classes/HudDemoViewController.m#L173) and [this](https://github.com/matej/MBProgressHUD/blob/master/Demo/Classes/HudDemoViewController.m#L249)) and do something similar with the ASIHTTPRequest API.

In addition you should manually hide the hud when the authentication dialog appears (a good place might be your controller's `viewWillDisappear:`) and show it again when the dialog is dismissed (in your controller's `viewWillAppear:`).

Comment: I am working for iPad, so viewWillAppear: or viewWillDisappear: will not work here :(

Comment: Than try if you can use any of the existing ASIHTTPRequest delegate callbacks. If appropriate callbacks aren't available, you might need to subclass ASIAuthenticationDialog add add your own delegate protocol that can notify you when this view appears and disappears. Then simply subclass ASIHTTPRequest, and override showAuthenticationDialog to show your custom ASIAuthenticationDialog subclass.